How do i bake iridescent paint?
I want to make a live iridescent paint, where it works properly (pic 2 before bake), and it's not just the flat base colour (pic 1 after diffuse bake), to export to unreal engine. Is it possible?




Iridescent colors shift based on the direction the camera views the surface. Unless your camera is in the same angle you won't get the same effect.

It is just like @NascentSpace said, iridescence is view dependent and cannot be baked or if it would only look like it at a specific view. Just like reflections. Sure you can bake a value for how smooth or rough a surface is, but you cannot bake what is reflected because it depends on the viewing angle and also (same for iridescence) the surrounding lights and environment.
